# In ChartJS, how do I render a horizontal bar chart, with labels above each bar, flush to the left?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm using the `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` library as advised, but there is no combination of `anchor` and `align` properties that produce the desired result.

I've tried all combinations of those props and nothing seems to work. For some reason, it is centering on the y-axis and I can try and add spaces the the labels to bring them flush to the right of the y-axis.

This is the goal:
[image]

Comment: In almost all questions here on SO, you should provide your code, or a [simplified version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of it that can be run by those who want to help you.  For your problem, you should explore the *numeric* case for the value for `align`, see [the docs](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#alignment-and-offset) at `... a number representing the clockwise angle`. Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3kr2evbd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is property named dataLabels where you can define your requirements.

```
   plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            offset: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'end',
                x: 10,
                y: -5
            },
        }
    }
```

Adjust the x and y value as per your requirements